# Internet Explorer won't update AJAX handled content on refresh?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, refresh

I have a page that grabs content from a XML file through a Jquery AJAX call.

The problem is it will update the content from the XML file on a refresh for every browser except IE.

I have tried to solve this with meta tags

```
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1"/>
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache,must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"/>
```

This is a small portion of the relevant javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$.ajax({type: "GET",url: "file1.xml",dataType: "xml", success: parseXml });
}

function parseXml(xml){
document.getElementById(eventMonthName).innerHTML=firstxmlvari.getElementsByTagName('month')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
```

Any suggestions would be very appreciated!

Comment: I don't know what backend technology you use but you should try setting the HTTP headers. In my experience older IE doesn't respond well to the meta tags. Here is how to manipulate the http headers in php. http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/headers.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, probably you run into IE's agressive caching...
Try setting the HTTP headers, but something that works for me, is appending the current time to the query string like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/echo/xml/",
        data: {
            _rnd: new Date().getTime()
        },
        dataType: "xml",
        success: parseXml
    });
});

function parseXml(xml) {
    alert(xml);
}
```

An example on JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/WVBDc/, check the outgoing HTTP requests.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use "cache: false" option which will work in same way that Akos Lukacs mentioned. Result is the same, but you don't have to create your own Date.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/echo/xml/",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: parseXml
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

As jQuery's .load method doesn't offer a convenient way of turning off cache, I add a timestamp parameter to my request, which is just ignored at the controller level:

```
$('#userDialog').load('/Users/Edit/' + someValue + '?timestamp=' + new Date().getTime(), function () {
...
});
```

or:

```
$('#userDialog').load('/Users/Create', { timestamp: new Date().getTime() }, function () {
...
});
```

This is indeed only needed for IE and still is as of version 10.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I had a similar problem (only in IE of course) with a dropdown that didn't refresh after the request. Adding a timestamp did the trick in combination with;

`$(document).trigger("ready");`

in the success function, cheers!