# Page refresh to update table not working in IE 11

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, datatables

In my main asp.net page I use a data table using "datatables.min.js" to display data in a tabular format. On a button click I am poping-up a Jquery modal dialogue. Once the new data is added the Modal dialog closes, and the main page refreshes showing the new row. This works fine in Chrome, Firefox. But when I try it using internet Explorer 11, even though the page refreshes I don't see the newly added row. I have to manually refresh the page again to see the newly added data row.

In my modal dialog code i use the "window.location.href" as shown below.

```
        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "/Region/Index",
            data: regionFormData,
            success: function () {
                $("#loaderDiv").hide();
                $("#myModal1").modal("hide");
                window.location.href = "/Region/Index";
            }
        });
```

I tried out location.reload(true); instead of `window.locatio.href`. But its still not working in IE 11.

I also tried out adding the Meta tag in the header of the master page (_Layout.cshtml) as shown below

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge;" />
```

But no luck.
Is there a way to get this working in IE 11 ?

Comment: Try setting `cache:false`  on your `$.ajax` request. Also try `window.location.reload()` and see if that helps

Comment: @zgood How to set cache:false. Is it a ine in the .ajax call ? please let me know

Comment: Yes, `cache: false` is a paramater in the ajax request. You could refer to the accepted answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646672/ie-does-not-refresh-after-ajax-get-posts) about how to use `cache:false`. You could also refer to the solution of adding a timestamp parameter to the request like [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619966/internet-explorer-wont-update-ajax-handled-content-on-refresh).

Comment: @sm101 its set like this in your request: `$.ajax({type: "POST",type: "POST",cache: false,data: regionFormData, success: function () { .. }});`

Comment: @zgood set cahe: false, And the IE 11 issue is gone ! awesome ! i didn't know that was an IE 11 cache issue. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's being cached.  Perhaps putting a random characters at the end of href part, ie:

```
window.location.href = "/Region/Index?abcd";
```